# HD Video in Chrome Browser is not working properly

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, gpu

I have an Android device with Android 4.2. It's a Box with an HDMI Output, to plug in to a TV.
This box is capable of playing 1080p HD-Videos in the media-player app. However when I try to display a 720p Video (downscaled via ffmpeg) in the chrome or chromium browser, the framerate gets horribly low. (It varies between 15fps and 22fps) You can't really enjoy the video...
When the video is not fullscreen, but in a smaller div-container it gets even worse!

In the `chrome://inspect`-settings I have set the flags:

- #ignore-cpu-blacklist
- #show-fps-counter
- #enable-gpu-rasterization (force enable)

When I do not set those flags, the video does not play at all.
On the video-screenshot in the top right corner you can see, that the browser almost takes none of the available GPU-memory! Why is that? Can I do something about it?

When I enter `chrome://gpu` it shows, that Hardware acceleration is supported. Nevertheless the output is just terrible...

Do you have any tips how to improve HD-video playback in the browser?

Best regards

[image: Screenshot of Video On the Top right you see the bad framerate]

[image]

Comment: Are you streaming the video from web or from your local storage?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am streaming it from the LAN. Streaming from the media-player works smooth. So I don't think it's related to network speed.

Comment: Okay. But, does the same happen when you play via web or from internal storage? I have no lags playing an HD 1080p video from youtube with the latest version of Chrome.